# How to call javascript function for many radio button sets?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 10 questions each having 4 radio buttons as options. I want to  validate whether all questions have a radio button checked. And call javascript function on submit button onclick.

Please help me with the javascript function.
 Can i use a 2d elements to target each radio button in each question in the javascript function.Please resolve the javascript issue.running this javascript i can only target the questions using the 1d array.

```js
function validateForm() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByClassName("surveyQuestions");
    var formValid = false;
    
    var i = 0;
    while (formValid == false && i < radios.length) {
        if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
        i++;
    }
    
    if (formValid == false) alert("Must Check Option !!");
}
```

```html
<form class="forward">
        <div class="surveyQuestions">
            <label>2.Who is your Favorite Forward ? </label>
    <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" >
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            Lionel Messi
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
           Cristiano Ronaldo
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option3" >
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
            Neymar Jr
            </label>
    </div>
            <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios4" value="option4" >
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
            Mohammed Salah
            </label>
    </div>
        </div>
            </form>
        
        
        <form class="midfielder">
         <div class="surveyQuestions">
            <label>3.Who is your favourite Midfielder? </label>
    <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            Toni Kroos
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
           Andreas Iniesta
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option3" >
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
            Kevin De Bruyne
            </label>
    </div>
            <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios4" value="option4" >
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
            Paul Pogba
            </label>
    </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        
        <form class="defender">
         <div class="surveyQuestions">
            <label>4.Who is your Favorite Defender ? </label>
    <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" >
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            Sergio Ramos
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
           Gerard Pique
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option3" >
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
            Leonardo Bonucci
            </label>
    </div>
            <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios4" value="option4" >
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
            Thiago Silva
            </label>
    </div>
        </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: You should add html an JS content in your question

Comment: have you tried something so far? If yes then show us your code!

Comment: You got down vote because you have not added any content in your question

Comment: @Kristianmitk i have added my html code and the javascript function please help asap.

Comment: While you're iterating through the radio buttons, check the `name` attribute of each checked one, and make sure all names are accounted for.

Comment: If you use query then this become more easy

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

Just modify your function something like below

```
function validateForm() {
            var totalQue = document.getElementsByClassName("surveyQuestions").length;
            var selectedAns = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']:checked").length;
            if(totalQue != selectedAns){
            alert("Must Check Option !!");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This will give you all radio buttons which are selected.

Comment: At the very least, you should mention that this code requires the use of jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use classes to your radios. For example:

```
<input type="radio" class="checkthis group_01" id="group_01_item_01">
<input type="radio" class="checkthis group_01" id="group_01_item_02">
<input type="radio" class="checkthis group_01" id="group_01_item_03">
<input type="radio" class="checkthis group_01" id="group_01_item_04">

<input type="radio" class="checkthis group_02" id="group_02_item_01">
// ...and so on
```

After this you can select all radios with `.checkthis` class, and a group by `.group_01` class, and an item with id.

Now you can use jQuery to find a selected from a group, like this:

```
var object_array = $('.group_01').find(':checked');
if (object_array.length > 0) {
    // you have a selected element
} else {
    // there isn't selected element
}
```

**UPDATED:**

Without jQuery, only native JavaScript:

```
var object_array = document.body.querySelector('.group_01:checked');
```

The if statement is the same.

Comment: then you need to use the native javascript querySelector() function

Comment: At the very least, you should mention that this code requires the use of jQuery...

Comment: I just updated the answer with native javascript code too.